# How to update javascript that has been executed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dependency-injection

How can I update or change a javascript loaded in a website dynamically?

E.g I have the below javascript on my website, and I want to replace or update the whole script with another script.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code already executed, you can change javascript on the server and force page refresh somehow..

Comment: You can also rollback all revertable actions step-by-step: remove event listeners, etc. But I believe, this workflow is broken..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use .unbind

```
$( "#fname").unbind( "change" );
```

or

```
var handler = myFunction() {
   //stuff
};

$( "#fname").unbind( "change", handler);
```

If you want to leave other events.  You have to trigger the unbind somehow though.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to remove whole of javascript file**

You can give the **script tag** id and then getElementById and remove it from the DOM and append another script tag

```
$('script#jsId').remove();
$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>');
```